# How to remove all text between <style> tags?

Tags: r, text-mining, gsub

I'm doing a text mining assignment on R, and I have a corpus that includes some html documents. I would like to remove the `<style>` tags and all the text between them, preferably with gsub function.

Example:

Turn this:

```
<style>
.s4-tn{
border-left: 1px #0071C5 solid;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: "Intel Clear", Verdana, verdana, san-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #0071C5; }

.s4-toplinks .s4-tn a.selected:hover{
    color:#1F497D;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<img id="corner" src="/sites/HR_ETM/SitePages/img/bottom_bar.png"/>
```

to this:

```
<img id="corner" src="/sites/HR_ETM/SitePages/img/bottom_bar.png"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `removeNodes`

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(txt,asText=TRUE)
styleNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//style")
removeNodes(styleNodes)
doc

> removeNodes(styleNodes)
NULL
> doc
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head></head>
<body><img id="corner" src="/sites/HR_ETM/SitePages/img/bottom_bar.png"></body>
</html>

>
```

To save your edited `XML` you can use `saveXML`:

```
> saveXML(doc)
[1] "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head></head>\n<body><img id=\"corner\" src=\"/sites/HR_ETM/SitePages/img/bottom_bar.png\"></body>\n</html>\n"
```

To select comment nodes use:

```
commentNodes <- getNodeSet(doc, "//comment()")
```

Comment: Indeed I would also :) But I think you can get some performances issues since you need to read all the DOM.

Comment: Fair point I think the OP needs to clarify what they want returned

Comment: Thanks! by the way, how can I convert the doc to character?

Comment: We are trying to eliminate also html comments that looks like `<!-- COMMENTS -->` using `styleNodes <- getNodeSet(temp, "//!")`, but it doesn't work. How can we catch these tags and remove them? Thanks

Comment: Use `getNodeSet(doc, "//comment()")`

Answer (score 3):

Avoid using regular expression here and use a html/xml parser.

```
txt <- '<style>
.s4-tn{
border-left: 1px #0071C5 solid;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
font-family: "Intel Clear", Verdana, verdana, san-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: lighter;
color: #0071C5; }

.s4-toplinks .s4-tn a.selected:hover{
    color:#1F497D;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<img id="corner" src="/sites/HR_ETM/SitePages/img/bottom_bar.png"/>'
```

Then you read and parse it. For example to get only "img" tags:

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(txt,asText=TRUE)
 xpathSApply(doc,'//img')
[[1]]
<img id="corner" src="/sites/HR_ETM/SitePages/img/bottom_bar.png"/>
```

#### PS : edited after comment.

Comment: This seems incomplete. The OP doesn't want the `<style>` content, he wants the remaining content after you strip out the `<style>` tags are the text between them. (Good point re using a HTML parser; you can do but trivial things with HTML using regexps.)

Comment: Thanks @agstudy. This Answers the example in the OP's question. I wonder how long before they post a comment saying that this was *just* an example and their real text could include any other arbitrary HTML markup. At that point I assume this answer will not work any longer?

Comment: I will post a better answer :) just I review how to negate an xpath element :)

Comment: @agstudy great approach.  Just out of curiosity is there a way to negate the `style` tags so it removes this content and everything else is left behind?  If there were other forms of content (say `<p>` tags) your approach wouldn't grab them.